# Tabs are breaking in Ext JS 6 when zoom out page

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, tabpanel

I'm using TabPanel with tab left position. When zoom out page scale to 90% left tabs are become broken. It's seen in Google Chrome 54.0.2840.59 m (64-bit), in Firefox latest version seem to be ok. Can you help me?

Screenshots:
100% page scale: http://prnt.sc/cwl6q0

After scaling to 90%: http://prnt.sc/cwld7e or http://prnt.sc/cwl6k9

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1it1

It's also seen in Kitchensink
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#advanced-tabs

Comment: Chrome 53 is not affected, my Chrome has started to auto-update, will report once that is through.

Comment: I have no problem in that fiddle with Chrome 54.0.2840.59 m